# How do I release this CGPath when I need to return it

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, memory-management, quartz-graphics

I have a method that returns a **CGMutablePathRef**, something like this:

```
- (CGMutablePathRef)somePath;  
{  
    CGMutablePathRef theLine = CGPathCreateMutable(); 

    CGPathMoveToPoint(theLine, NULL, 50, 50);  
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(theLine, NULL, 160, 480);  
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(theLine, NULL, 270, 50);

    return theLine;  
}
```

The Xcode/Clang static analyzer warns that there's a potential leak. The docs say to call **CGPathRelease()** but where would I put that?

If I put that before the method returns won't that cause **theLine** to disappear before it's returned to it's caller?

Comment: Are you still having problems with Xcode/Clang complaining at you?

Comment: same problem with you, still seeking for answer.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If a method name begins with `new`, clang will expect it to return an object with a retain count of 1. In other words, renaming the method from `somePath` to `newSomePath` will quiet the Analyzer.

If you actually want to autorelease the CGPathRef, you *might* be able to cast it to an NSObject and then call autorelease. I know that works for CFTypes, I'm honestly not sure if CGPathRef qualifies.

Comment: Too bad that this doesn't work with C-functions that return CG objects. :(

Comment: @Pascal Is the analyzer complaining about a C-function? There are naming conventions for those, too. I think names containing `Copy` or `Create` are expected to return retained items.

Comment: Awesome, using `create...` as function name did the trick, thanks!

Comment: @benzado Thank you for saving me.  Using create on my C-function worked like a charm.  Is this specific to Apple's compiler or C in general?

Comment: @benzado +1 amazing piece of knowledge, do you have a reference to the documentation that mentions this? Thanks.

Comment: I can't remember any reading any documentation but I remember it being mentioned in one of the WWDC 2011 or maybe 2012 videos. One of the ones about ARC, sorry I can't remember the exact session.

Comment: I know this is kind of an old question but its still valid, and for those coming across it now, FYI: it seems 'create' is no longer a valid option in the latest versions of Xcode. 'new' works as well as 'copy'.

Answer (score 8):

How about creating a mutablepath, passing it to your building function, then using and releasing it:

```
CGMutablePathRef mPath = CGPathCreateMutable();
[buildPath:mPath]; //adds reusable lines etc
...do something with it...
CGPathRelease(mPath);
```